# Andriod Development Zoom in, page swipe all in one animation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am very new to Android Development and for a project of mine I want to be able to have multiple animations for a fragment. The ones I want is to be able to swipe left and right and zoom in and out for each fragment. An example would be to have an Image in each fragment, and I could zoom in and out and swipe to the next image. I have seen examples online where this is achieved using a grid view. Is there any example or resources online where I can do this?

In my example I have here is that I used Viewpager 2 for the swipe animation then I attempted to implement a zoom-in feature but when I ran it overwrites the viewpager and I am unable to swipe pages only zoom in and out of that image. Can I somehow add the zoom feature in the PageTransformer class? I know this is probably a very poor way of going about it.

I know probably that in the in the PageTransformer class I need to add the zoom in and out animation how would I do that?

```
package com.example.viewpager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));

        PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
        photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_child_of_the_king);
        photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_mighty_fortress);
        photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_quiet_place);
        photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.all_the_way);
}
```

//PageTranformer class

```
package com.example.viewpager;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; 
import android.view.View;
import com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView;
//import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
      private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
      public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0f);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1f);
            view.setTranslationX(0f);
            view.setScaleX(1f);
            view.setScaleY(1f);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0f);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swiping with Viewpager makes sense in a way.

Do you load all the images into the same Layout?
Are you inflating a Fragment and inflate the single Layout onto it and then load the image into the displayed ImageView?

If so, for zooming in and out you might have to modify this approach to register touches correctly:

```
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
   private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
   private ImageView imageView;  
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
      return true;
   }
   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
         mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
         mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));
         imageView.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
         imageView.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
         return true;
      }
   }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks If you can see the question I posted above that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I am loading the images into the same layout. This is done in a separate class. see code below. Now The code that you provided am I able to just implement that to the Main Activity class? Would I be able to call: 
 viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
 viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));  as well as scaleGestureDetector function?

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private int[] images = {
        R.drawable.a_child_of_the_king,
        R.drawable.a_mighty_fortress,
        R.drawable.a_quiet_place,
        R.drawable.all_the_way,
        R.drawable.because_he_lives,
        R.drawable.before_jehovahs_awful_throne,
        R.drawable.before_jehovahs_awful_throne2,
        R.drawable.beneath_the_cross_of_jesus
};

public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelayout, 
 collection, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
               collection.addView(viewGroup);
    return viewGroup;
}

 @Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewGroup) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

 @Override

public int getCount() {

    return images.length;

}



@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
    return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
}
```